# DJANGO REST - CLASS BASED VIEW - POST,GET requests do not work as they are defined

Tags: json, django, ajax, http, django-rest-framework

I've set up a class-based view that handles all the requests

- views.py

```
#Imports

from django.shortcuts import render
from .serializers import UserSerializer
from rest_framework import viewsets
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from  django.http import HttpResponseForbidden
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status

#Imports End

class UserApiView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        raise HttpResponseForbidden("Get Requests are not allowed here")

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        if request.is_ajax():
            serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        else:
            raise HttpResponseForbidden("You are not allowed to acess this page")
```

- this is the serializer class (  **serializers.py**  )

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','email','password']
```

- The urls.py are being handel by the DefaultRouter()

```
from django.urls import include, path
from rest_framework import routers
from .views import UserApiView

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'user',UserApiView,basename="takis")


urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

I want the backend to handle the view just as said in the post and get request methods , but they do not seem to get executed.

I can normally access the url , without a forbidden error and it accepts requests even if they are not ajax.

Answer (score 1):

I am not very clear what you are trying to do, what I understand you want to accept `post` request and reject `get`. you can extent `APIView` instead of `ModelViewSet`

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView

class UserApiView(APIView):
  
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        # handle get

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        # handle post
```

Answer (score 1):

A Viewset is only usefull if you overwrite one of these methods.

- `create()`
- `retrieve()`
- `update()`
- `partial_update()`
- `destroy()`
- `list()`

If you need to overwrite `get` and `post` method you are better off with `APIView` or `GenericAPIView`.

Comment: ```Api View``` and whatever inherits it, does not seem to work as it throws an ```AttributeError: type object 'UserApiView' has no attribute 'get_extra_actions'```